# How to reconstruct information from a graph of an oscillation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, wavelength

We are given a graph of the position of a wave (amplitude). 
How can we calculate the wavelength, frequency and the maximum speed of a particle attached to that wave?

We have

*Speed = wave length $\times$ frequency*,

*$W=2 \pi \times$ frequency* ,

$V_{max}=A\times W$.

So how to calculate A?

[image]

Comment: Please help if you have any idea ?

Comment: well, this is some type of sinusoid. Wavelength, in a very rough and general way, is the spatial period of the wave, the length required to come back to its original starting point. In this case, wavelength is 4 meters for B and 2 meters for A. Does the problem give more info?

Comment: They gave me speed and they are asking frequency and max speed ?

Comment: Please add that to the problem itself. When asking a question you should state the full question or the particular concept you are having trouble with, and then list what you know and/or what you've tried.

Comment: I added please Help i am really stuck on this.

Comment: Ok, posted below. If it helps, hit the check on the left. If it doesn't help, do not click it and I'll try to help some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2\pi\omega \cdot A = v_{max}$ so try $v_{max}=\lambda \omega=A \cdot 2\pi\omega$. Solve for what you want, $A=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}$ where $\lambda$ is different for each wave, as I enumerated in the comments, $\lambda_A=2$m and $\lambda_B=4$m.

I hope I answered your question right from what you're telling me. I will stress that in order to get a solid response, post your FULL question in clear terms and make sure you post everything you know and tried. Try to focus it down to conceptual questions. We want to help, but we also don't want to explicitly do your homework. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Why you used wavelength instead of A?

Comment: What is A supposed to be?

Comment: Ampltude or max of formula x=Acos(wt) which is A,

Comment: I see. one moment